# UIAlertView title does not display

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

I have created an alert as follows

```
UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Title"
                           message:@"message"
                           delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil];

 [alert1 show];
```

[image]

But it does not display the title. How can I fix this?

Comment: R you trying in iOS8?.If so use UIAlertController.

Comment: r u using in Xcode6 or below versi

Comment: this code is working in iOS8 alwell i have checked

Comment: yes.. Xcode 6 and iOS8

Comment: @dheeru so y in my case title is not display.. :(

Comment: remove the app and run again hope work

Answer (score 2):

I try in `Xcode 5.1.1` in your code is working fine in my Xcode, see the output

[image]

and i also try in  `Xcode 6.0.1` your code is working fine in my Xcode, see the output

[image]

if u r using in  `Xcode 6.0.1` in `swift`

> UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of 
>   UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead.

```
UIAlertController * alert1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* aaction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"okay" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                      [alert1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                  }];
[alert1 addAction:aaction];
[self presentViewController:alert1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

another choice

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

need more help use this link http://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/

Comment: try this this is working fine, if u need any assistance i surely help with u

Comment: still I am in same state .. can u please help me out

Comment: r u try in xcode 6 - objective - C or swift bro, what the error u meet

Comment: using Xcode 6 and Objective C.. And issue is Title is not display and message is comming with bold as like title

Comment: Sory dear.. its not possible

Comment: k do one thing , create the new project in Xcode, in first  view controller call this alert in view did load and check that working fine or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this for iOS 8

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"I am an AlertView" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                      }];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just removed the following method from my ViewController category class and it's working fine!

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
   // My Code
}
```

Comment: I struggled with this for so long and had all but given up until I found this. Thanks! I think you should accept your own answer since all the others are just showing you how to create an alert, but the code you posted really causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode 6.0 UIAlertView class:

> UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle
>   of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead.

On swift ( iOS 8 and OS X 10.10 ), you can do this:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "Alert Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:handleCancel))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
                println("User click Ok button")
            }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

func handleCancel(alertView: UIAlertAction!)
        {
            println("User click cancel button")
        }
```

Comment: They haven't asked for swift they have asked for objective-c -1

Comment: I said the method is deprecated on Xcode 6 and posted an example of Swift, he could simply search for the UIAlertController syntax for objective-c, or it seems something too difficult for you?

Comment: If they wanted it in swift they would have asked for it in swift but they have asked for objective-c so this makes your answer incorrect. Also please don't add insulting comments to the end of your comments, your the one who has provided an incorrect answer most people would just downvote and not provide a reason at least I gave you a reason so you can correct. Now my downvote will remain because of you being rude and insulting.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the solution in Swift.  Though it doesn't directly answer the question posed in Objective-C, it's a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code using UIAlerController for XCode 6 and IOS 8

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                 message:@"Your Message"
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                        }];
   UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                           }];

   [alert addAction:ok];
   [alert addAction:cancel];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope it is useful to you..

Comment: Sorry but still Title is not display :(

Comment: I dont see any reason why the answer above would not work. @Myaaoonn Could you provide more of what's your code.

Comment: @Myaaoonn have you tried copy pasting the answer provided above? Technically that should do it.

Comment: @Teffi Ofcourse, I know its our main habit.. But badly no effect.. I don't know what is the issue, is it of my Xcode issue..