# Do I have to handle deprecation when I'm supporting a lower iOS-version?

Tags: ios

For instance, let's say my iOS-application supports down to iOS 7.0, and I want to make an alert. In iOS 7, I would use `UIAlertView`. In iOS 8/9, this has been deprecated by `UIAlertController`. Do I have to check `if currentVersion > iOS7`, and then create BOTH alerts, an `alertView` for iOS7 and an `alertController` for iOS8+? Or is it okay to use `UIAlertView` in an iOS7-app, even though it will be running on iOS9+ devices eventually?

Will I ever need to check what the current iOS-version is, and implement multiple objects (one for each version), in **simple matters like this**?

Comment: Market share stats you might find useful: https://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/

Comment: basically you need to worry about everything which is deprecated in the actual SDK your are using to compile the project.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecation is just a note that a feature may be removed in a future version. The deprecated class or method still works, though.

So you can simply continue using `UIAlertView` and face the risk of breaking in a future iOS version. It still does work on iOS 9. There's no guarantee that it will continue to work on iOS 10, though.

The best solution here is to [check whether `UIAlertController` is available at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25656478/400056). If it is, use that class for your alert, otherwise fall back to `UIAlertView`.

You usually do *not* check the iOS version! It's better to check whether a method or class is available, except in the very rare cases were Apple *explicitly* tells you check the iOS version: this happens when a method that was considered to be private was made public by Apple.

Comment: Quite often deprecated features will "work" but they will have issues

Comment: @BradThomas: What kind of issues do you mean? In the case of `UIAlertView`, that thing always had issues which is why it's succeeded by `UIAlertController`. Other than that, I'm not aware of any deprecated class or method which has changed its behavior (until it was removed, of course).

Comment: In our project, upgrading to iOS8 caused flaky behavior with UIAlertView. Questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228729/ios-8-uialertview-uialertcontroller-not-showing-text-or-buttons

Comment: @BradThomas: Thanks for sharing! That's really the first time I've heard about issues with deprecated classes/methods.

Comment: @DarkDust But since my project supports iOS 7 I'm not actually receiving the deprecation. I only see the deprecation when creating a new project, only supporting down to iOS 8 or 9. Does this mean I *could* be using a lot of deprecated code (that has been deprecated after iOS7), without knowing it? Is there a quick way to analyze the code in my project for objects and methods that are deprecated in newer iOS-version (I.E to show deprecation warnings that isn't deprecated in iOS 7, but might cause problems for iOS8, 9, 10 etc.).

Comment: @Sti: I'm not aware of a way to do such a check. You do not get a deprecation warning as you're still targeting a version (deployment target) where the class/method is not yet deprecated (and there won't be a replacement in that version).