# UIAlertController title is always nil with iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have a problem since iOS8 and Xcode 6.0.1, the title of my alert dialogs doesn't appear. So I changed my UIAlertView to UIAlertController but I have the same issue...

The title of my alert is always to nil and the displaying is very ugly because I don't have the serparator lines.

Do you know why i have this ?

```
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But this is the result

[image: Alertview without title]

```
(lldb) po alert.title
nil
(lldb) po alert.message
message
```

Thank you.

Comment: Used Excat same code and its working here

Comment: @Bhumit I tested on another clean project and it works fine too but I don't know what could be in conflict with UIAlertController in my actual project...

Comment: It's working from my side

Comment: @Varsha Me too with a new project but not with my current project. I don't know why :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem thanks to @Myaaoonn !

[UIAlertView title does not display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927676/uialertview-title-not-display)

> I have just Remove the following method from my ViewController
>   Category Class And its working fyn!

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
   // My Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the UIAlertView like this:

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:<#title#>
                            message:<#msg#>
                           delegate:nil
                  cancelButtonTitle:<#cancel button#>
                  otherButtonTitles:<#buttons#>,nil] show];
```

Does the title still not show?

Comment: It still doesn't work on iOS8 but works on iOS7...
iOS8 result : http://s9.postimg.org/y176nl6a7/alerti_OS8.png
iOS7 result : http://s28.postimg.org/c8n75e7kt/alerti_OS7.png